# Postgres group by timestamp into 6 hourly buckets

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following simple table:

```
ID      TIMESTAMP               VALUE
4   2011-05-27 15:50:04 1253
5   2011-05-27 15:55:02 1304
6   2011-05-27 16:00:02 1322
7   2011-05-27 16:05:01 1364
```

I would like to average the `VALUES`, and `GROUP` each `TIMESTAMP` day into 6 hourly buckets. e.g 00:00 to 06:00, 06:00 to 12:00, 12:00 to 18:00 & 18:00 to 00:00.

I am able to group by year, month, day & hour using the following query:

```
select avg(VALUE),
  EXTRACT(year from TIMESTAMP) AS year,
  EXTRACT(month from TIMESTAMP) AS month,
  EXTRACT(day from TIMESTAMP) as day
    from TABLE
      group by year,month,day
```

But I am unable to group each day into 4 periods as defined above, any help is most welcome.

Comment: Take a look at [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html). See my fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c2089/2.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think grouping the integer value of the quotient of the (Hour of your timestamp / 6) should help. Try it and see if it helps. 
Your group by should be something like

```
group by year, month, day, trunc(EXTRACT(hour from TIMESTAMP) / 6)
```

The logic behind this is that when the hour part of the date is divided by 6, the int values can only be

```
    0 - 0:00 - 5:59:59
    1 - 6:00 - 11:59:59
    2 - 12:00 - 17:59:59
    3 - 18:00 - 23:59:59
```

Grouping using this should put your data into 4 groups per day, which is what you need.

Comment: A simple and elegant solution, many thanks for your help this works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks even though mine was for MSSQL basically same idea just using DatePart(hh,timestamp) / 6

Answer (score 1):

As of Postgres 14, there is the `date_bin` function to help.

`date_bin(stride, source, origin)`

**stride** is an expression of type interval. In your case, '6 hours'

**source** is the timestamp you're working with.

**origin** is where the intervals start counting from. For your case, starting it at midnight will get you the 00:00, 6:00, 12:00, 18:00 buckets you're looking for.

Applied to the query above, it'd look like:

```
select avg(VALUE),
  date_bin('6 hours', TIMESTAMP, '2011-01-01 00:00') as time_bucket
from TABLE
group by time_bucket
```

Full date_bin documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN