# Group By Date with specific hours

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to do a `group by` on this bunch of data, based on the date, but with `23:00` to `22:59` as begin hour and end hour.

For example, for these data :

```
2014-11-05 23:04:58.0
2014-11-05 23:23:03.0
2014-11-05 23:51:54.0
2014-11-05 23:54:29.0
2014-11-05 23:58:14.0
2014-11-06 06:13:23.0
2014-11-06 06:29:58.0
2014-11-06 06:58:27.0
2014-11-06 08:21:56.0
2014-11-06 08:24:01.0
2014-11-06 23:13:47.0
2014-11-06 23:27:55.0
2014-11-06 23:30:34.0
2014-11-06 23:40:52.0
2014-11-06 23:58:53.0
2014-11-07 06:00:37.0
2014-11-07 06:23:47.0
2014-11-07 06:28:27.0
2014-11-07 06:44:13.0
```

I'm expecting something like :

```
Count | Date
-------------------
10    | 2014-11-06
9     | 2014-11-07
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgres group by timestamp into 6 hourly buckets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157718/postgres-group-by-timestamp-into-6-hourly-buckets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this aggregation by adding one hour to the date:

```
select date(timestamp + interval '1' hour) as thedate, count(*)
from table t
group by date(timestamp + interval '1' hour);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EXTRACT function to return the hour and group by that. For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(date), date
from tableName
group by EXTRACT(hour from Date)
```

For more info, see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-datetime.html)